# Custom message to "This account is currently not available" when user login is disabled

Tags: debian, ubuntu, login, lxc, proxmox

I have a Lxc container inside a Proxmox host. I need to prevent that the Proxmox admin can login inside my container. To do so I disabled root login in `/etc/passwd`. When the Proxmox admin uses `pct enter` to login as `root`, the message "This account is currently not available" is correctly displayed.

I wish to add my custom message. There is any way to customize this message?

Comment: If the proxmox admin is root on the proxmox host, you probably can't prevent access to your container (example: using `nsenter`). But ok any layer of security is still something good to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `root` login has its shell set to `nologin`, instead of logging in it runs the `nologin` command.

Check out the [manpage of nologin](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nologin.8.html) for more information.

As pointed out in the manpage, you can create a text file at `/etc/nologin.txt` to display a custom message. Otherwise it will use the default message.